# How to hide the form using ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a search form. When I click on the `ng-click` button it gives some product details. Once I get the details, I want hide that form.

**product.html**

```
<form name="search_form">
  <div class="search" flex layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-magnify" class="icon search-icon"></md-icon>
    <input class="search-input" ng-model="vm.form.search" type="text" placeholder="Place your URL here.."  flex>
  </div>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" aria-label="LOG IN" ng-click="vm.submitPost(vm.form);">
     Get Details
  </md-button>
</form>
```

**product.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.product')
        .controller('ProductController', ProductController);

    /** @ngInject */
    ProductController.$inject = ['$http', '$location'];
    function ProductController($http, $location, Auth, $rootScope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.submitPost =  function(userData) {
            //console.log(userData);
            $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/product-search',
                method: 'POST',
                data: userData
            }).then(function(res) {
                console.log('success');
                vm.Product_Name=res.data.Product_Name;
                vm.Brand=res.data.Brand;
                vm.Color=res.data.Color;
                vm.Price=res.data.Price;
                vm.Rating=res.data.Rating;
                vm.Image=res.data.Image;
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert('Please enter url');
            });
        };
    }
})();
```

My form looks like this:

[image]

In that image I have marked that form. When I click on the `get details` button I want to get details of product and at the same time hide that form.

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable with `ngHide`:

After the promise in the `submitPost` function, set a variable to true:

```
vm.hideForm = true;
```

Use `ngHide` with the form in the markup:

```
<form ng-hide="vm.hideForm === true">
```

Comment: or simply `<form ng-hide="vm.hideForm">`

Comment: i did like what you said but before click on "Get details" button both form and button are not appearing

Comment: Obviously, because the button is part of the form and the entire form is being hidden!

Comment: what do you mean by 'taken out the button'?

Comment: Just use `ngHide` on the div element in your form.

Comment: means i placed it in outside the form. Now i am seeing only button. I want to see also that input field present in the form. After i click on button both has to disappeared.

Comment: what exactly do you want to hide? You want to see the input field and the button but thats the whole of your form!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107229/discussion-between-hemanth-kumar-h-j-and-tarun-dugar).